# How to effeciently perform multiple element swaps with a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, swap

Within a numpy array of 48 elements, I have a series of swaps that I need to make.

```
34 -> 21 -> 42 -> 26 -> 34
36 -> 19 -> 44 -> 28 -> 36
39 -> 16 -> 47 -> 31 -> 39
```

where `x -> y` means the element at index x must go to the yth index. I'm trying to think of an efficient way to do this since the numbers are quite random and this is just one of the series of swaps that I need to make.

For example:
Given the following array

```
original = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

I want to make the following swaps

```
1 -> 4 -> 6 -> 1
```

so I end up with

```
swapped = ['a', 'g', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'f', 'e', 'h']
```

so the 1st index element went to the 4th index, the 4th to the 6th, and the 6th to the 1st.

Comment: Are these numpy arrays? Or lists?

Comment: @nullUser These are numpy arrays. I'll edit the question

Comment: What format will your swap indices be in? Will they be hardcoded or dynamic?

Comment: @ThisIsAQuestion The indices are hardcoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the most efficient way to perform a single of those sequences:

```py
swaps = [34, 21, 42, 26, 34]
arr = np.arange(48)

from_idx = lst[:-1]
to_idx = lst[1:]
arr[to_idx] = arr[from_idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this.

```
def swap(input, index):
    start_index = index[0]
    for next_index in range(1, len(index)):
       input[start_index], input[next_index] = input[next_index] , input[start_index]
    
    return(input)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
    index = [2,3,6,2]

    output = swap(input, index)
    print(output)
```